# Block undefined routes/paths in apigee

Tags: apigee

I have a proxy defined in Apigee with an end point which has quite a few different controllers and paths. I only want to expose 2 of these via apigee (a get and post). I can't work out how to stop anyone else being able to access the other endpoints through the apigee proxy.

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm I understand your requirement right, the target API exposes multiple paths. Of all those paths, you would want to expose 2(GET and POST) paths via Apigee to your consumers.

This can be done using [conditional flows](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/fundamentals/flow-configurations#aboutconditionalflows). Create three conditional flows in your proxy endpoint. Two conditional flows for two paths you would want to expose. You may use combination of paths and HTTP verbs in the `Condition` tag.

Use the third conditional flow without any conditions as a catch all block. You can use the [raise fault policy](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/raise-fault-policy) in the third conditional flow to return appropriate error to the consumer.

Your proxy endpoint should look something like this -

```xml
<Flows>
    <Flow name="get-resource">
        <Description>Get resource</Description>
        <Request/>
        <Response/>
        <Condition>(proxy.pathsuffix MatchesPath "/resource") and (request.verb = "GET")</Condition>
    </Flow>
    <Flow name="post-resource">
        <Description>Create resource</Description>
        <Request/>
        <Response/>
        <Condition>(proxy.pathsuffix MatchesPath "/resource") and (request.verb = "POST")</Condition>
    </Flow>
    <Flow name="Unknown Resource">
        <Description>Unknown resource</Description>
        <Request>
            <Step>
                <Name>RaiseFault-UnknownResource</Name>
            </Step>
        </Request>
        <Response/>
    </Flow>
</Flows>
```

And the raise fault policy would look something like this -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<RaiseFault async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="RaiseFault-UnknownResource">
    <DisplayName>RaiseFault-UnknownResource</DisplayName>
    <Properties/>
    <FaultResponse>
        <Set>
            <Headers/>
            <Payload contentType="text/plain">Resource not found</Payload>
            <StatusCode>404</StatusCode>
            <ReasonPhrase>Not Found</ReasonPhrase>
        </Set>
    </FaultResponse>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
</RaiseFault>
```

If this is not the requirement please clarify it and I'll try and update the answer accordingly.